# System.UnauthorizedAccessException appears while accessing Temporary Internet Files

Tags: c#-3.0

I have created a utility for cleaning Temporary internet files but when the application tried to access Temporary Internet Files, exception appear that

"System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'c:\users\test\AppData\Local\Temporary Internet Files' is denied."

The application runs from an Administrator account and UAC is off.
I am running the code on Windows 7 enterprise N 64 bit

I have also tried to remove the security but nothing happend.

```
public static void RemoveDirectorySecurity(string FileName, string Account,      
FileSystemRights Rights, AccessControlType ControlType)
    {
        // Create a new DirectoryInfo object.
        DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(FileName);

        // Get a DirectorySecurity object that represents the  
        // current security settings.
        DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();

        // Add the FileSystemAccessRule to the security settings. 
        dSecurity.RemoveAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(Account,
                                                        Rights,
                                                        ControlType));

        // Set the new access settings.
        dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);

    }
```

Any suggestion to resolve this issue?

Thankx and Regards

Comment: do you run it elevated? (aka "Run as Administrator")

Comment: I have done that but still issue is not resolved